# Android. Как реализовать загрузку изображений с камеры телефона на внутреннюю память телефона?

Tags: java, android, изображения

То есть по кнопке открывается фотик, делается снимок  и он загружается на телефон. По другой кнопке можно просматривать фотки. Да, реализацию я находил, но при загрузке изображения телефон писал, что изображение не загружено. На одном сайте(А. Климова) прочитал, что старые примеры могут не работать. Вопрос: как все это реализовать для новых версий андроид?
Вот моя нерабочая реализация, делается снимок, помещается в ImageView, оттуда помещается в память телефона:

```
public void onClickCameras(View view) {
    try {
        // Намерение для запуска камеры
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Выводим сообщение об ошибке
        String errorMessage = "Ваше устройство не поддерживает съемку";
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Вернулись от приложения Камера
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                // Получим Uri снимка
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();

            }
            // Вернулись из операции кадрирования
            else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                // Получим кадрированное изображение
                assert extras != null;
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                // передаём его в ImageView
                ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.polSnimok);
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
                //imageView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        }


}
    private void performCrop(){
        try {
            // Намерение для кадрирования. Не все устройства поддерживают его
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            String errorMessage = "Извините, но ваше устройство не поддерживает кадрирование";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```